# How to apply border for bar-stacked chart in highcharts when data is zero in the series?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

How to **apply border in the stacked bar chart** when the series contains zero value? When the series contains zero value, stacked bar don't visible instead of that how to set the border for that empty bar. Please check this [fiddle]:https://jsfiddle.net/fekkyDev/3b1jahsg/1/

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'bar'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Stacked bar chart'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas']
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Total fruit consumption'
        }
    },
    legend: {
        reversed: true
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            stacking: 'normal'
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'John',
        data: [0, 3, 4, 7, 2]
    }, {
        name: 'Jane',
        data: [0, 2, 3, 2, 1]
    }, {
        name: 'Joe',
        data: [0, 4, 4, 2, 5]
    }]
});
```

Comment: to apply border you could add `bar: {
        borderColor: 'black',
        borderWidth: 1
      }` in `plotOptions` but the apples columns still wont be visible, until there is a value for it

Comment: oh ok, but how to add an border without the value ?

Comment: For zero value there will not be any bar generated so it doesn't generate the border also. What is the expected result?

Comment: When zero value need to render grey bar with border

Comment: Check this example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/4L6oc7fy/. Try to be more precise please, because it's obvious that zero value won't render a bar.

Comment: I had a similar Question. You can see the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52181643/overlapping-and-rounded-stack-in-stacked-column-graph-in-highcharts). This might help you.